# Ip address for my computer and the Ip of the server that I am linked to

Tags: web, ip

Thank you in advance for someone who answers this question. I used javascript to find out the ip address in my computer, the code is as following

function getip(json){
    alert(json.ip); // alerts the ip address 
}

I get one ip address which say 123.32.11.1

However when check my ip address on my mac it says I am connecting to xxx and the ip address is 10.1.223.123

I am confused about what's the two different ip address means.
If I am trying to use ip address to identify my geolocation I will need to use the first one. Does that mean only the first ip address means where I am located?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your IP address is probably 123.32.11.1. Any address in the range 10.x.x.x is a private IP address; sometimes used by your computer for internal business ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#IPv4_private_addresses)).

Another option is that you have 2 IP addresses by virtue of being connected on 2 separate networks.